# Grafana hide query from user

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am trying to build a Grafana dashboard with an Elastic data-source but when I view the network traffic I see that the browser goes directly to the elastic DB, this means that if a user wanted to they can change the query and get whatever data they want. I want to be able to limit the data to this specific user.
I was thinking of limiting it with a filter for the specific user but am open to suggestions.

Comment: If you set xpack with Elasticsearch, you can limit what a user can access. Apparently it should be possible when you define the connection in grafana (which I never used so I can't say for sure..) see: https://logz.io/blog/grafana-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rifling through the grafana forum I found this
https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-templating-by-logged-in-user/1724
So apparently it's not possible.